# primefaces commandbutton does not work if datatable has no selection

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use primefaces 3.5 on liferay6.1.
I have the following code

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head />
    <h:body>

        <h:form id="form">
            <p:commandLink
                action="/views/initialMenu.xhtml?javax.portlet.faces.PortletMode=view&amp;javax.portlet.faces.WindowState=normal">
                <h:graphicImage url="/Home.png" styleClass="basicImageStyle" />
            </p:commandLink>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p:panel header="Step 4">
                <p:panel header="Align application unique settings to common terms">
                    <p:dataTable id="settings" var="setting"
                        value="#{step4Bean.settings}" rowKey="#{setting.name}"
                        selection="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting}" selectionMode="single"
                        emptyMessage="No settings found" style="width:85px;">
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{step4Bean.onRowSelect}"
                            update=":form:settingDialog " oncomplete="settingDialog.show()" />

                        <p:column headerText="Application unique setting name">
                            <h:outputText value="#{setting.name}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Setting description">
                            <h:outputText value="#{setting.description}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Setting value space">
                            <h:outputText value="#{setting.valueSpace}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Default value">
                            <h:outputText value="#{setting.value}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Mapped to the common term">
                            <h:outputText value="#{setting.mapping}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Exact matching">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{setting.exactMatching}"
                                disabled="true" />

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Comments">
                            <h:outputText value="#{setting.comments}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>

                </p:panel>
                <p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save alignment"
                    actionListener="#{step4Bean.saveAlignment}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Previous" id="prevBut" ajax="false"
                    action="/views/step3View.xhtml?javax.portlet.faces.PortletMode=view&amp;javax.portlet.faces.WindowState=normal" />
            </p:panel>
            <p:dialog id="settingDialog" modal="true"
                header="Setting #{step4Bean.selectedSetting.name}"
                widgetVar="settingDialog" resizable="false" width="500"
                showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value"
                    styleClass="grid">
                    <h:outputText value="Solution unique setting name:  " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.name}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Setting description:  " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.description}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Setting value space:  " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.valueSpace}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Setting description:  " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.description}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Default value:  " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.value}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Mapping:  " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.mapping}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.sortedMappings}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputText value="Exact matching:  " />
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
                        value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.exactMatching}">
                        <p:ajax update="settingComments" />
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <h:outputText value="Comments:  " />
                    <p:inputText label="settingComments" id="settingComments"
                        value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.comments}"
                        disabled="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.exactMatching}">
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:commandButton value="Propose new registry term" id="proposeBut"
                        oncomplete="settingDialog2.show()" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="OK" id="okBut"
                    update=":#{p:component('form')}" oncomplete="settingDialog.hide()" />

            </p:dialog>
            <p:dialog id="settingDialog2" header="New Registry Term" modal="true"
                widgetVar="settingDialog2" resizable="false" width="500"
                showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value"
                    styleClass="grid">
                    <h:outputText value="Enter the registry term name:  " />
                    <p:inputText label="registryTermName" id="registryTermName"
                        value="#{step4Bean.selectedSetting.mapping}">
                    </p:inputText>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="OK" id="ok2But"
                    actionListener="#{step4Bean.addProposedTerm}"
                    update=":#{p:component('settingDialog')},:#{p:component('form')}"
                    oncomplete="settingDialog2.hide()" />
            </p:dialog>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
    </f:view>
```

with the corresponding SessionScoped bean:

```
package org.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.test.ontology.Ontology;
import org.test.utils.StringComparison;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.IndividualImpl;

@ManagedBean(name = "step4Bean")
@SessionScoped
public class Step4Bean {
    private List<String> registryItemsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Ontology ontology;
    private List<Setting> settings;
    private Setting selectedSetting;
    private String newRegistryTerm = "";

    public Step4Bean() {
        super();
        try {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Step1Bean step1Bean = (Step1Bean) context.getApplication()
                    .evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{step1Bean}",
                            Step1Bean.class);
            ontology = step1Bean.getOntology();

            step3Bean step3Bean = (step3Bean) context.getApplication()
                    .evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{step3Bean}",
                            step3Bean.class);

            settings = step3Bean.getSettings();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        registryItemsList = ontology.getInstancesOfRegistryClass();
        for (int i = 0; i < settings.size(); i++) {
            Setting set = settings.get(i);
            SortedMap map = new TreeMap();
            for (int j = 0; j < registryItemsList.size(); j++) {
                map.put(registryItemsList.get(j),
                        StringComparison.CompareStrings(set.getName(),
                                registryItemsList.get(j)));
            }
            SortedSet map2 = entriesSortedByValues(map);
            Iterator itr = map2.iterator();
            String str = "";
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                str = itr.next().toString().split("=")[0];
                list.add(str);
            }
            set.setMapping(str);
            List<String> list2 = reverseList(list);
            set.setSortedMappings(list2);

        }

    }

    private List reverseList(List myList) {
        List invertedList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = myList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            invertedList.add(myList.get(i));
        }
        return invertedList;
    }

    <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> entriesSortedByValues(
            Map<K, V> map) {
        SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(
                new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> e1, Map.Entry<K, V> e2) {
                        int res = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                        return res != 0 ? res : 1; // Special fix to preserve
                                                    // items with equal values
                    }
                });
        sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
        return sortedEntries;
    }

    public List<String> getRegistryItemsList() {
        return registryItemsList;
    }

    public void setRegistryItemsList(List<String> registryItemsList) {
        this.registryItemsList = registryItemsList;
    }

    public Ontology getOntology() {
        return ontology;
    }

    public void setOntology(Ontology ontology) {
        this.ontology = ontology;
    }

    public List<Setting> getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }

    public void setSettings(List<Setting> settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public Setting getSelectedSetting() {

        return selectedSetting;
    }

    public void setSelectedSetting(Setting selectedSetting) {
        this.selectedSetting = selectedSetting;

    }

    public String getNewRegistryTerm() {
        return newRegistryTerm;
    }

    public void setNewRegistryTerm(String newRegistryTerm) {
        this.newRegistryTerm = newRegistryTerm;
    }

    public void saveAlignment() {
        System.out.println("SAVE");

    }



    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {

    }

    public void addProposedTerm() {

        selectedSetting.getSortedMappings()
                .add(0, selectedSetting.getMapping());

    }

}
```

The problem is that the commandButtons do not work if the table is empty, or no selection is made.

Am I missing something?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Do you have `<h:form>` tags which encloses `<commandButton>`? possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/892994

Comment: Yes <h:form> encloses commandbutton. The strange is that the buttons work only if a table row is selected

Comment: Can you post your managed bean codes and the page including `<h:form>` tag(s)?

Comment: If I remove the two dialogs, then it works fine...but why is this happening?